# How can i extract links from string with html content using htmlagilitypack?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, html-agility-pack

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberoflinks; i++)
{
    string downloadString = client.DownloadString(mainlink+i+".html");
    var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
    var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                        .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                        .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
}
```

The problem is that HtmlWeb().Load require a html url but i want to Load the string downloadString which have already the html content inside.

Update:

I tried this now:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberoflinks; i++)
            {

                string downloadString = client.DownloadString(mainlink+i+".html");
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                document.Load(downloadString);
                var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                                                .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                                                .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
            }
```

But i'm getting exception on the line:

```
document.Load(downloadString);
```

Illegal characters in path

What i'm trying to do is to download/extract all .JPG images from each link.
Without download the url first to the hard disk but download the content to a string extract all images links ending with .JPG in this html then download the JPG's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to process a string of HTML using the `LoadHtml()` method of `HtmlDocument`.

From the source code:

> `public void LoadHtml(string html)`
>
> Loads the HTML document from the specified string.
>
> `param name="html"`
>
> String containing the HTML document to load. May not be null.

The `Load` method expects a filename, which the is reason for the message about `illegal characters in path`.